# Unity position y is escaping

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started tutorial https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/moving-the-player and I don't understand why, after clicking Play, Position Y is automaticly, constantly changing value. I was following tutorial and I don't what I could miss. The efect is that my ball after clicking Play is disappearing immediately..

Maybe somebody had similar problem?

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
private Rigidbody rb;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
}}
```

Comment: Pleas use unity3d tag for such.

Comment: It is normally your game object have a rigidbody. If object is not on the ground, It will fall to down [more information](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Player object's y-coordinate is automatically changing means it's basically falling downward automatically.

Remember that gravity is enabled for rigid bodies automatically and maybe you haven't attached a rigidbody to the main floor play area.

Go over the tutorial again and follow along the steps carefully, especially checking if a rigidbody has been attached to the plane.

Answer (score 0):

The ball is falling down, it needs to land on another rigidbody that is not susceptible to gravity (gravity scale = 0)